# Logic: Showing that a conditional statement is false.

Tags: logic

Suppose that p and q are statements so that $p\rightarrow q$ is false. What does this say about p and q's relationship?

My thoughts:

The only way to show that the conditional statement $p\rightarrow q$ is false, is if p: true, q:false.
To say that the conditional is false does that imply anything other than that statement q is false when p is true. Does it say anything about the other truth table positions?

Edit:

If p and q are known and $p\rightarrow q$ is known to be false, that obviously means that p is true and q is false. But what about statements where p and q can both be true or false but q is always false when p is true:

p="n is odd and", q="n is evenly divisible by two"
The statement form $p\rightarrow q$ is clearly false. Does this count as showing that the conditional statement is false? And if it does is it only a specific case of $p\rightarrow q$ being false and doesn't tell us anything general about any statements p and q where $p\rightarrow q$ is false?

Edit2:

Does it make sense to say that the conditional relationship apply to any statements wholly unrelated i.e.

p="2=2" and q="3=3", does this satisfy $p\rightarrow q$

Comment: What does it mean? The "other tt positions" are what they are: the tt allows us to compute the truth value of formula $p \to q$ from its components. If we already know that the formula is false, as you say we know the truth values of both $p$ and $q$, due to the fact that there is only one row in the tt that falsifies the formula.

Comment: The proposition $p \to q$ is false exactly when both $p$ is true and $q$ is false. The reason this seems to go against our intuition about $\to$ meaning "if" is because when we make statements like if $p,$ then $q$ in real life, we're really making more universal statements, so we need to introduce quantifiers to get the negation for that statement.

Comment: "Does it make sense to say that the conditional relationship apply to any statements wholly unrelated?" Yes, it is a connective, like *conjunction* that can be used with two statements whatsoever.

Comment: "p="2=2" and q="3=3", does this satisfy p→q" What does it mean? It  is simply: "if 2=2, then 3=3". Is it true? Yes

Comment: Feedback: to "falsify" in philosophy of science means 'to refute/disprove', while in most other contexts means 'to alter to deceive'. However, In the above question, "falsify" appears mean 'to make false' (Meaning 3), but on further consideration turns out to probably mean 'to *be* false' (Meaning 4, which is confusingly adjectival rather than verbal). In short, the question will be more readable if each occurrence of "falsify" is rephrased more plainly.

Comment: @ryang Thank you. I meant "it shows something to be false".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your response. I thought of conditional statements as showing a clear link between statements where one is in some way informed by the other. But from you comment I  gather that is not the case.

Comment: **IF** you consider the "standard" truth-functional conenctives of classical logic: "not", "and", "if..., then...", they express no "link" between statements. They are used only to produce compound statements from simpler ones, and to "compute" the truth value of the result from that of the components using the corresponding truth table.

Comment: @ErikEriksson You're welcome. Your latest edit missed the "falsify" in Line 4 and in the title. My feedback is because your position/understanding/confusion of the issue at hand is directly related to and clarified by what you mean each time you write "falsify".

Comment: @ErikEriksson In any case, the Answer to your Question is this (further to Mauro's most recent comment): (A) the relationship among the ***logical*** truth values of $p$ and $q$ and $p{\to}q$ is independent of (B) the meanings assigned to $p$ and $q.$

Comment: @ryang Ever do I strive towards improving. Thanks for the feedback and hopefully all the evidence of "falsify" is gone now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it make sense to say that the conditional relationship apply to
> any statements wholly unrelated?

Yes. IMHO, requiring some pre-existing relationship between propositions $P$ and $Q$  in order to make sense of $P\to Q$ needlessly hobbles the application of the rules of logic.

Logical (material) implication is usually introduced to beginners by either:

(1) Simply stating it as logic operator $\to$ with the truth table:

[image]

(2) Simply defining: $~~P\to Q~~\equiv ~~ \neg (P \land \neg Q)$

> My thoughts: The only way to show that the conditional statement
> $p\rightarrow q$ is false, is if p: true, q:false.

From the above definitions, you can see that you can indeed see that this is indeed the case.

---

If you are familiar with the basic methods of formal proof, both of these "definitions" can be easily justified from first principles without assuming any pre-existing relationships between $P$ and $Q$. (See my [blog posting](https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/) on this topic. Requires some knowledge of those basic methods.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have come to realise that my conception of conditional statements come from the proofs given in univariable calculus, where short proofs of formulas have iff or if relationship, most often between related propositions. This skewed my view of what a conditional statement is. I have begun a jurney to better understand math and was recommended Susanna Epp's book on Discrete Mathematics. My next book is Richard Hammack's Book of Proof. Hopefully I will get a better understanding of formal proofs then.